# How does gpostpro "escape from the monad"?

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads, recursion-schemes

I am trying to understand how this very abstract recursive function from the Haskell `recursion-schemes` package works (or, indeed, what it does!) - from [this file](https://github.com/ekmett/recursion-schemes/blob/74ccfaea0e336e84978e47fca35b94e0c5f476f2/Data/Functor/Foldable.hs):

```
class Functor (Base t) => Corecursive t where

  [...]

  -- | A generalized postpromorphism
  gpostpro
    :: (Recursive t, Monad m)
    => (forall b. m (Base t b) -> Base t (m b)) -- distributive law
    -> (forall c. Base t c -> Base t c)         -- natural transformation
    -> (a -> Base t (m a))                      -- a (Base t)-m-coalgebra
    -> a                                        -- seed
    -> t
  gpostpro k e g = a . return where a = embed . fmap (ana (e . project) . a . join) . k . liftM g
```

In particular, what I want to understand is: how does it apply the `g` function which mentions the monad type constructor `m`, but then return a value of the `t` type, which doesn't mention or depend on `m`? I thought escaping from arbitrary monads was impossible in Haskell!

I first loaded the source file into Intero to try to use its type-at-point feature, but that attempt [failed](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/issues/264).

I then loaded it into GHCi using `cabal repl`, and tried to follow the types through the composed functions one at a time, using GHCi to help with type inference, by commenting out various bits of the definition. However, when I got to the `fmap`, I couldn't work out what to comment out, because if I uncommented the recursive `a` invocation but commented out other stuff, I thought it probably wouldn't even compile because the partially-commented-out *definition* of `a` wouldn't have the right type.

Comment: You can place `_` instead any expression to ask GHC about its type.

Comment: And wrt. escaping: `t` is of `Recursive` class, which means it has `* -> *` kind. This hints that gpospro return type isn't escaping anything and is wrapped into something. Which is probably a monad.

Comment: @arrowd The above type signature would be impossible if that was the case because you cannot have a return type that has kind `* -> *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get ghci to tell me what the types of subexpressions were by surrounding them in `(`...`:: _)`.

Turns out, the trick is, the "distributive law" `k` allows you to shove the monad inside the temporary `Base` type, and then the `embed` method allows you to dispense with the temporary `Base` type and get back to `t`. If indeed the concrete type `t` doesn't mention `IO`, then it would be impossible to write such a `k` (safely) for the IO monad, for example. So there is no magic here - i.e. no way to use this function to escape from monads which would otherwise be unescapable, like IO.

Comment: Mark your own answer as answer, then.